# Two radio button groups with Thymeleaf, use th:field but override name

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm generating inputs on a form dynamically. All of my input selections will be saved to the pizza object's ingredients. I have a pair of radio buttons for selecting dough and sauce, as only one should be selected from that ingredient category. The selections from each category need to be saved to ingredients. My selections from one radio group overrides the other because th:field overrides name but both button groups need to correspond to submit to the same field. How can I make selections from both without overriding the other and still make sure that the input is saved to the corresponding field (add selected input to pizza's set of ingredients)

```
<form autocomplete="off"
      th:action="@{/processOrder}"
      th:object="${pizza}"
      method="post">

    Select dough type:
    <div th:each="dough : ${doughs}">
        <input type="radio" id="doughSelection1" th:value="${dough.id}" th:id="${dough.id}"
               th:field="*{ingredients}" name="dough"> <label for="doughSelection1">[[${dough.name}]]</label>
    </div>

    Select sauce type:
    <div th:each="sauce : ${sauces}">
        <input type="radio" id="sauce" th:value="${sauce.id}" th:id="${sauce.id}"
               th:field="*{ingredients}" name="sauce" th:field="${pizza.ingredients}"><label for="sauce">[[${sauce.name}]]</label>
    </div>

    Check Protein type:
    <div th:each="protein : ${proteins}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="protein" th:value="${protein.id}"
               th:field="*{ingredients}"><label for="protein">[[${protein.name}]]</label>
    </div>

    Check Veggie type:
    <div th:each="veggie : ${veggies}">
        <input type="checkbox" th:id="${veggie.id}" th:value="${veggie.id}"
               th:field="*{ingredients}"><label th:for="${veggie.id}">[[${veggie.name}]]</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the Java code of the `pizza` object class?

Comment: I would make them checkboxes, and use javascript to make sure they can't select more than one more from each "group". I don't think you can use radio buttons for what you want.